# Are there square/ rectangle/ U openable/ open panel conduits that have one side panel that can be opened & closed?

Tags: cables, ethernet, cable-management, fiberglass

Are there square/ rectangle/ U openable/ open panel conduits that have one side panel that can be opened & closed?

- Will be doing a up / down cable/ pull for current/ future optic Fiber etc. so the rest of its journey is hidden under false ceiling frame (shown in pic).
- It's largely Outer Wall to Center of Condo thing as ISPs dangle fibers externally (yes, welcome to Asia)
- I am sharing a picture of this from my Phone shortly so that it becomes clear

[image]

**Color Code for Items in Diagram/ Picture:**

- **Green:** Pull Boxes (Since they recommend [replacing Conduit bends with Pull boxes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c8PgrvTrwAM))

  - One above False Ceiling Panel
  - One somewhere below the Desk (Between Floor & Desk Height)
- **Yellow Thick:** Direction of Cable

  - Above: Inner Wall towards further indoors
  - Below: Outer Wall to Inside of Wall
- **Pink**: 2 Possible wall locations for Conduit with Panel

**Required Solution:**

I'd like to place such a U - square/ rectangle Conduit that has an open-able panel in one of the Walls in the Corner.

**Update to Question: Please update answers as required**

- I'd want it not be Surface mounted on the wall but
- Recessed / concealed into the wall with only Removeable Panel / related parts at Surface. Pref 1.25 / 1.5"
- Hence the point of the question.
- Someone may cry why do you want/ need. Please do not bother.
- I am trying to future proof against certain stuff that's been experienced before.

### Are there such items and what are they called?

### This is not a shopping question, but trying to figure out what items can be used to fulfill the need for the required application scenario.

Answer (score 4):

Surface mount gutter if you want the wireway where the red box is would work. Wire mold also makes some listed wireways that look much nicer than standard gutter. Added per op comment, if there are taps in the wireway / gutter it must be accessible per NEC 378.56, but if just used like conduit it can be concealed the same as conduit. There are 2 main types some are hinged and some have a flat metal cover that are screwed to the gutter. I am sure with some clever trim it could be easy to conceal and open at a later time, the max fill is 20% 376.22.A and the nice thing is less than 30 conductors no derate is required. 376.22.B.

Comment: Try "surface mount raceway" too, Wiremold, Panduit, and others make raceways for datacom wiring, and some are split raceways with internal dividers that allow you to route power and communications in the same raceway.  The products made for datacom are designed so that the bend radius of the corner / elbow fittings is suitable for network / fiber optic cables.  Surprisingly expensive.

Comment: Update to Question: I'd want it not be Surface mounted on the wall but recessed / concealed into the wall with only Removeable Panel / related parts at Surface. Hence the point of the question. 
Pref 1.25 / 1.5"

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for what we brits would call "trunking", it comes in various shapes and sizes, some rectangular some more curved and has a removable lid.

Comment: Update to Question: I'd want it not be Surface mounted on the wall but recessed / concealed into the wall with only Removeable Panel / related parts at Surface. Hence the point of the question. 
Pref 1.25 / 1.5"

Comment: I'm not aware of any specific products for that. You could partially recess trunking into the wall but you would probablly have to leave it at least somewhat proud to allow removal of the lid.